# Update account information PDO/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create edit.php so users can change password and change their information like email, username.

Username is the session user logged, so if username change i need UPDATE SESSION with the new username. it doesn't work. I dont know why.
Thank you for your help. This is the code edit.php

```
<?php 
require('includes/config.php'); 
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 
?>
<?php
class info {    
}
$username= $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username';
$query= $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute( array(

          ':username' => $username, 
));
$query->setFetchMode (PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'info');
while($r= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $email = $r->email;
    $namefull = $r->namefull;
    $usertype = $r->usertype;
    $password = $r->password;
    }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Username deve avere almeno 4 lettere.';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row['username'])){
            $error[] = 'Username già in uso.';
        }
    }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error[] = 'Inserisci una email valida';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
        $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row['email'])){
            $error[] = 'Email già in uso.';
        }
    }
    if(!isset($error)){
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET (username,email,usertype) VALUES (:username, :email,:usertype) WHERE username='".$username."'");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':usertype' => $_POST['usertype'],
            ));
            header('Location: edit.php?action=joined');
            exit;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

      }
}
?>
```

This the action form for the reset password, i create edit-reset.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Password deve contenere almeno 4 lettere.';
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Conferma password deve contenere almeno 4 lettere.';
    }

    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
        $error[] = 'Le password non sono uguali.';
    }


    //if no errors have been created carry on
    if(!isset($error)){

        //hash the password
        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        //create the activasion code
        $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

        try {

            //insert into database with a prepared statement
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('id');

            //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Cambio password";
            $body = "<p>La tua password è stata cambiata!</p>
            <p>Amministrazione Dixard</p>";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
            exit;

        //else catch the exception and show the error.
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        //aggiornare la sessione con la nuova password




    }      

}

?>
```

Here the is the Two forms ( Change email, username, usertype AND change password) :

Username
                          ">
                      
                      
                          Tipologia account
                          ">
                      
                      
                          Email address
                          ">
                      

                      Salva

```
              <h2 class="strong-header large-header">Change Password</h2>
              <form role="form" action="edit-reset.php" method="post" novalidate>
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password corrente</label>
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password_corrent" id="password" class="form-control"  required>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Nuova Password</label>
                      <input type="password" placeholder="Nuova Password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"  required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password-repeat">Conferma Nuova password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm"class="form-control" placeholder="Conferma Nuova Password" required>
                  </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cambia Password</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're checking in your `edit.php` script if the username or the email is already used, you're not excluding the `id` of the current user. So, the user will always be obliged to changed his username **AND** email each time he want to change one of them.

Furthermore, you're not updating `$_SESSION['username']` after updating data in database to keep the user logged in (assuming that the username was modified).

Comment: Yes i need update session with the new username data. But the problem is that username and email doesn't change. Database data not change 
  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = $id)');
  $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']   ));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($row['username'])){
   $error[] = 'Username exist.';
  }

 }

Comment: 1. I think there is a problem in your update request ; you need to take a look at this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html. Your request should be more like this : `UPDATE users SET username = :username, email = :email, usertype = :usertype WHERE id = :id;`

2. In your previous verification, retrieve the current user ID with a simple request `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username;` and add this id in your condition while you're checking if username is not already used : `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND id != :id;`